# Can analog bandwidth be modeled as an RC low-pass filter in this way?

Tags: bandwidth

The analog bandwidth of [this](https://www.picotech.com/download/manuals/PicoScope6000ABSeriesDataSheet.pdf) scope is given as 250 MHz.

When we see the term analog bandwidth, can that be modeled as an RC low-pass filter whose roll-off frequency (-3 dB point) is 250 MHz?

Comment: The spec seems a bit ambiguous in other ways also: *"250 MHz (TA150 probes / 50 Ω)"*. If we take that to mean measuring a 50 ohm source with the supplied probes that have 9.5 pF load capacitance, then the probing setup itself would already have about 3 dB loss at the frequency. Possibly it means that the spec applies to either TA150 probes with 0 ohm source *or* the 50-ohm terminated input mode, but it would be strange to have exactly same performance for 1 Mohm and 50 ohm input modes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, 'bandwidth' without any further qualification means a -3dB bandwidth.

What happens beyond the -3dB point is unspecified. I would expect an oscilloscope, or any analogue data capture tool for that matter, to roll off far more steeply than a single order RC. It consists of multiple stages, each stage will have a bandwidth. You can expect all of them to be rolling off as soon as the frequency is safely past 250 MHz, giving you a high order fall away in response.

Comment: Not just after it, but also what happens literally anywhere other than the -3 dB point. A system may exhibit significant peaking before it hits -3 dB. Though a good oscilloscope (with properly compensated probes!) won't, naturally. Many RF filters make claims of "0.1 dB flatness" in some frequency range, meaning the gain/attenuation doesn't deviate by more than 0.1 dB over that range (a more useful metric, for many applications, than the -3 dB bandwidth).

Answer (score 7):

Assumptions aren't great here.  For example, I have an old TDS460, which is rated 350MHz, but still has meaningful response up at 600, 800MHz even; it seems  to drop off at roughly a 2nd-order response.

DSOs are more likely to have low-order responses, I would say, thanks to the simpler AFEs (analog front ends).  These days, there are basically a couple go-to chips that handle the whole thing -- switchable/variable gain and offset, and differential output to drive a high-performance ADC; they have bandwidth of some 100s of MHz to low GHz, even when used in lower performance scopes.  (Bandwidth is therefore determined more by any additional filtering in the signal path, and the capability of the ADC.)

If I had to guess, I would guess the PicoScope fits into this category.  But that's a guess, based on assumptions, and if you need to know, you'll have to figure it out yourself.  A detailed teardown, or direct measurement of frequency response, ought to provide a reasonable answer to this.

Conversely, some ancient analog scopes used elaborate multi-section tuned amplifiers with quite severe bandwidth limitations: effectively the system formed a dozens-order filter with -3dB at the rated frequency, and almost a brick wall beyond!  Consider the chain of coils in the vertical deflection amplifier of the Tek 551:

[image: Tek 551 vertical deflection and delay line]

<sup>From: https://w140.com/tekwiki/wiki/Delay_line#/media/File:551_leftint.jpg</sup>

The two rows of 7 tubes, bottom left, with the coils below (short sections on the white rods), form a distributed amplifier; the delay line (left and top-left) is composed of still more coils, alternating with capacitors, to introduce a time delay.  The amplifiers have a strict lowpass response.  The delay line, may still have nominal gain above cutoff, but its phase response will not be as intended.

---

As for unqualified "bandwidth", generally we mean the -3dB point, but it could also be a cutoff where performance simply isn't guaranteed anymore; they might mean a specified gain up to 250MHz, with more or less gain beyond 250MHz simply being undefined; while a lowpass characteristic might be typical, it's not a necessity that it be to satisfy such a specification.

It could be that gain and phase bounce around beyond this cutoff.  Consider the bandpass response of a transformer: the lowest lowpass cutoff is defined by low-frequency equivalent parameters (leakage inductance LL and stray capacitance Cp), but the overall response needn't be a 2nd order lowpass.  Indeed, a Guanella transmission line transformer for example has unremarkable LL and Cp, but can have practical (flat) frequency response many octaves above the cutoff given by LL and Cp.

Or, and more to the point: as I recall, several of the early cheap, portable, semi-consumer DSOs (Tek TDS1000s? early Rigols? others?), generally suffered peaks in the frequency response, even within (albeit towards the upper edge of) the rated bandwidth.  The trouble is this: it doesn't take much peaking to greatly enhance the time-domain response (rise/fall time, say) of a signal, and it seems these oscilloscopes leaned hard on that fact to achieve their bandwidth (in terms of apparent step response), at expense to signal quality.  (Typically the ideal desired frequency response for an oscilloscope is somewhere between Bessel and truncated Gaussian; both are quite "shallow" filter types.)

Comment: Are these *go-to chips that handle the whole thing* ASICS or are they commercially available. Any hints?

Comment: LMH6518 and friends for example.